# Adding two __m128 types via Accelerate framework

Tags: sse2, accelerate-framework

I need to add/mul/sub two `__m128` (float) variables using Accelerate framework. But, I can't find function to do that. All Accelerate framework functions takes `int__vector__` type instead `float__vector__` type. I find function for dividing `'vdivf'`, but I need to add/mul/sub too. 
Can anyone tell me, how to add/mul/sub two `__m128` (float) variables using Accelerate framework? Something like this: `_mm_add_ps`, `_mm_sub_ps`, `_mm_mul_ps` but using Accelerate framework API.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to use the Accelerate Framework for this ? Why not just use the intrinsics directly ?

Comment: I think, if Apple provide API for using MMX, SSE etc., will be better to use this API. I need to support PPC and Intel processors family, Accelerate framework will be processed CPU command support automaticly. In addition, if something will be changed in future, I think, using Accelerate framework I will need to make less changes.

Comment: OK, but you don't want to call Accelerate functions just for single vectors - that would be hopelessly inefficient and pointless - you need to process reasonably sized arrays otherwise the function call overhead will wipe out any gains from using SIMD.

Comment: Thank you, Paul, but problem in next: I have an existing library on C++ for Windows platform and I need to use SSE2 with minimum! code changes. This code use `_mm_add_ps` and etc functions, I need to replace calling `_mm_add_ps` and etc functions with analog from Accelerate framework, because of mentioned reasons. Maby you can tell me, what use instead?

Comment: Thank you Paul, I was hoping that I missed something and just have not found that functions.

Comment: No problem - I have converted that last comment to an answer now (see below) and expanded on it a little further.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need an API for basic arithmetic:

```
__m128 x, y;
__m128 z = x + y;
__m128 w = x - y;
__m128 t = x * y;
```

An API would be totally unnecessary for these operations, so Accelerate doesn't have one.

That said, if you have existing code which uses the SSE intrinsics (`_mm_add_ps`, etc), and you're really trying to make "minimum code changes", why are you changing anything at all?  The SSE intrinsics work just fine on OS X as well.

Comment: "You don't need an API for basic arithmetic" What do you mean? That this operations will be automatically use SSE instructions?

Comment: @Lexandr: yes, they will.  However, as I noted, if you already have working code that uses the intrinsics, *don't change it*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Accelerate is a higher level API than using SSE2 intrinsics. SSE intrinsics map to single *instructions* which operate on one vector at a time. Accelerate provides a higher level API of functions which operate at a much larger granularity, typically with arrays of a reasonable size. To port your existing code you should just stick with SSE intrinsics, and if you really do need PowerPC support then you'll need to #idef the SSE code and write an equivalent AltiVec implementation for the ppc build. I doubt this will be worth the effort however - Apple stopped selling PowerPC Macs around 7 years ago, so the market for PowerPC apps must be very small by now.